# Unity Pink Texture On WebGL

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, image, unity-webgl

I'm trying to follow a youtube tutorial for my new game(images puzzle) and by using it's implementation on github to upload it later on facebook.

When I run the game inside unity editor its work without any problem, but when I export the game to exe or WebGL I get pink images background instead of the image am using.

Youtube tutorial link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrM7uCxtM6E).
GitHub repository link [here](https://github.com/SebLague/Programming-Practice).

The game works Fine inside unity
[image]
But shows pink images on web browsers and exe games
[image]
Why the images are showing pink background?

Comment: The pink background is how unity displays a missing texture (or shader), Unity removes any files it thinks aren't used at build time, so somehow unity thinks the texture/shader you are using isn't being used (referenced in the scene) so removes it, try putting in a folder called "Resources" in your root Assets folder see if that helps, files in there are always included in the build.